# What is the need of Handler objects in android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I was just reading about the `Handler` objects and its uses in android. It is a way to pass the data/status from some background thread to the UI thread.

Suppose there is a `TextView` in the UI, we just need to update the status to "Completed", once the work is done. What is bad in the below logic. Why do we then `Handlers`?

Can the same functionality achieved by the following logic.

```
public class BackgroundThread implements Runnable {

    TextView textView;

    BackgroundThread(TextView tv) {
        this.textView = tv;
    }

    public void run() {
        /* Do the background time consuming work here */

        /* We already have a reference to the UI ob Text View object */
        /* Use that to update the UI */

        textView.setText ("Task Completed");
    }
}
```

We can start the background thread from the Activity like

```
new Thread (new BackgroundThread (this.findViewById (R.id.my_text_view))).start();
bt.start();
```

Comment: This code will crash. You can't touch UI elements outside the UI thread. For this reason (and many other) you need to use an Handler

Comment: @RoiDivon So it is illegal to modify the UI element even though we have its valid reference in some thread?

Comment: Yes. It's illegal to modify them outside the UI thread. It doesn't matter "how" you got that reference